# Проблема формирования URL при настройке вебсокетов в Spring

Tags: java, spring, websocket

В приложении имеются группы чата. Для них я настраиваю Stomp следующим образом. Беру из базы идентификаторы групп и создаю URLы, на которые подписываю юзеров.
Этот подход неправильный, так как ws конфигурируется при старте, а группы создаются во время выполнения. Можно ли сконфигурировать ws во время выполнения? Или изначально создать пути и впоследствии привязывать их к определенной группе, но тогда не понятно сколько их создавать. Как можно решить эту проблему?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    private OrgService orgService;
    private String[] urls;

    @Autowired
    public void setOrgService(OrgService orgService) {
        this.orgService = orgService;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        urls = orgService.getAllOrgs().stream().map(el ->  "/allusers" + el.getId())
                .peek(logger::debug).toArray(String[]::new);
        String[] urls2 = new String[urls.length + 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < urls.length; i++){
            urls2[i] = urls[i];
        }
        urls2[urls2.length - 2] = "/message";
        urls2[urls2.length - 1] = "/user";
        registry.enableSimpleBroker(urls2); 
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }


    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/messages").withSockJS();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не совсем правильно используете протокол STOMP. Данный протокол имеет методы подписки и отписки на очереди и топики. Первое что на гуглил относительно STOMP и spring https://habr.com/ru/post/187822/

Как видите там говорят о командах SUBSCRIBE

```
 SUBSCRIBE
 id:sub-1
 destination:/topic/price.stock.*
```

Очереди и топики формируются в момент подписания на них, и, если не ошибаюсь, уничтожаются, если подписантов нет.

**UPDATE**

Еще раз повторю, для динамического подключения как раз придуманы отношения subscribe/unsubscribe...то есть можно сделать небольшие правки в примере (в теле функции connect()) из приведенной вами статьи:

```
foreach(var group: currentUser.groups){

    stompClient.subscribe('/topic/greeting_' + group, function(msg){
                             showGreeting(JSON.parse(msg.body).content);
                    });

}
```

Отправлять в такого рода топики и очереди можно через следующим образом

```
  String destination = "/topic/greeting_" + group;
  this.messagingTemplate.convertAndSend(destination, quote);
```

Все это описано в статье которую я приводил ранее. В вашей статье просто все на анотациях, и само собой анотации налагают ряд ограничений, которые вы пытаетесь обходить. Хотя надо просто сменить сам подход к отправке сообщений...тот же messagingTemplate вам даст такую возможность.

Comment: я настраивал брокер сообщений по этой инструкции. http://spring-projects.ru/guides/messaging-stomp-websocket/ . И насколько я понял, брокеру сообщений необходимо дать пути, по которым он будет рассылать сообщения, а на клиенте нужно подписаться на эти пути. У меня всё работает. Проблема лишь в динамическом добавлении их в брокер

Comment: обновил ответ, привел более детальные примеры.

Comment: действительно. Я и использую template. Просто я думал конфигурировать обязательно. Закомментил содержимое configureMessageBroker и всё заработало.